# How do I connect two homes to the same network?

Tags: networking, vpn

I have two homes. My wife and family are most often in Iowa and I work mostly in North Carolina. We have two homes. Some entertainment services we have are for a household. The services work seamlessly on the home network. The services have travel features to project to a TV from a phone or table, but this is really inconvenient. I'm looking for a solution where I can connect the two homes into a single network so that registering devices on the network is seamless. Is that possible?

Comment: Not a direct solution, but a nice visualisation of what you might do: https://www.linksys.com/support-article?articleNum=132865 - note the different IP ranges for both locations in order to avoid conflicts. Something like this might work, but how you could set it up depends on your hardware and isn't done with a few mouse clicks. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no. At each location, there is a router connecting all the devices, such as computers, monitor cameras, and even "smart" washing machines, to the internet. This is a [local area network (LAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network). The router usually assigns IP addresses for these devices. For example, in one house, a PC might be assigned address 192.168.1.3, but in the other, that address might be used for a WiFi speaker. However, the router in each house has a single, **unique**, IP address assigned by the internet service provider (ISP) each uses.

Since there may be 10,000,000 devices in the world with IP 192.168.1.3, you need to address the *router* in the home, with its unique IP address, to talk to a device in that location.

- There is the concept of a site-to-site [virtual private network (VPN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn) that allows two disparate LAN's to be connected together seamlessly. Check with some VPN providers for *pricing*, such as [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/pricing/), [Twingate](https://www.twingate.com/blog/aws-vpn-pricing), or [Micosoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/). You may find a VPN makes throughput slow, however, as well as costly.
- Another alternative is to create a [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) in each home. This would allow all devices in one home to talk with the web server in the other. The server can make available data (e.g., files such as documents or videos), or allow streaming (e.g., a web cam). Setting up the server depends on the ISP. For example, here are what claims to be [directions for Verizon FIOS](http://nerdposts.blogspot.com/2009/04/web-how-to-set-up-web-server-w-fios.html). However, some ISP's do not assign a long-term static IP address to a router, so your connection might occasionally need to be reset. Some ISP's specifically *prohibit* setting up a web server without permission.

  **N.B.** Without VPN, the server is *available to the entire internet*. There are many malefactors looking to view through your room cameras, to download your files, or to hack your server to serve *them*. This is *not* a good alternative for one without expertise in hardening a web site.